# How does python draw on the specified image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to write the operations and parameters that I usually use in drawing in a function. In the future, just pass x and y to draw according to the default parameters. But now the question I am facing is, how do I determine which picture `plt.plot` is drawing on? For example, I want to draw two curves on a picture.

```
   def draw(x,y):
        ...            %some operations
        plt.plot(x,y)  % draw picture operations
        ...            %some operations

   draw(x,y),
   dray(x2,y2)
```

How to ensure that these two curves are drawn on a picture. That is, what parameters do I need to pass to make `plt.plot` focus on the picture I specify.

```
def plotLine(coordinate,figName='test',xylabel=[],ax=None):
    # assert(len(coordinate)<=2)
    if (len(coordinate)==2) :
        x=coordinate[0]
        y=coordinate[1]
        assert(len(x)==len(y))
    else:
        y=coordinate
        x =np.linspace(0,len(y)-1,len(y))

    minn=min(y)
    maxx=max(y)
    
    plt.switch_backend('Agg')

    if ax == None:
        fig,ax = plt.subplots()
        fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(3.5, 1.5), dpi=300, facecolor='w')
        plt.subplots_adjust(right = 0.98, top = 0.98, bottom=0.35,left=0.32,wspace=0, hspace=0.2)
        ax.set_xlim([0,len(x)])
        ax.set_ylim([0,maxx+maxx/3])
        plt.xticks(fontsize=5)
        plt.yticks(fontsize=5)
    
    bar_width = 0.35
    opacity = 0.8
    lsmarkersize = 2.5    
    lslinewidth = 0.6
    
    ax.plot(x,y,'-', linewidth=1, markersize=lsmarkersize, markeredgewidth=0)
    plt.savefig(figName+".png",bbox_inches='tight',dpi=500)
    # os.system("code "+figName+".png")
    if ax!=None:
        return ax
    else:
        return plt.gca()

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y=[1,2,3,4,4,5]
ax = plotLine([x,y])

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y=[12,13,14,15,16,17]
plotLine([x,y],ax=ax)
```

I tried to pass ax as a parameter. But the picture drawn at the end is blank.

Comment: Matplotlib has a an [instructive tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) on how to create, organize, and fill subplots, and their gallery contains several examples of code one can adapt.

Comment: In this tutorial, two curves are drawn on two pictures, but I want to draw on one picture.

Comment: Matplotlib has object oriented features also to offer and is the suggested standard. You should take a look into those concepts. Read [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html) for starters

Comment: And the problem is? Create one subplot and provide the same `ax` object as a parameter of your function to draw the curves on.

Comment: I tried it. But the pictures displayed are blank. Nothing is drawn. I put the code I wrote in the question. thank you

Comment: Didn't you get `UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.`. Remove this line.

Comment: You are so amazing. After I removed it, it can be displayed. I run it on a server. The server has no graphical interface. That's why I added that sentence. But if the sentence is added to the function, nothing will be displayed, but if I put it outside the function, it will be displayed normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subplots` to specify the axes to plot on. For example, create a figure with a single subplot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

For your function you could do the following

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def draw(x, y, ax):
   ax.plot(x, y)

def dray(x2, y2, ax):
   ax.plot(x2, y2)
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should pass ax as a parameter to the function, and use ax.plot to plot in the function?

Comment: Why write two identical functions. I want to write a function that I can call repeatedly. I only need to pass a parameter representing the picture, and then it will draw on this picture

Comment: Yeah it could be just one. I just assumed each function has some seperate functionality (based off the "some operations" comments) you wanted to put in

Comment: I tried it. But the pictures displayed are blank. Nothing is drawn. I put the code I wrote in the question. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not attempting to modify your code. This is more a general approach answer. Imho, it is better (in terms of keeping track of what's going on) to define the figure and plots outside the function and doing only the actual plotting inside the function.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)

#the plotting function, taking ax and label as optional parameters
def draw_the_line(x, y, current_ax=None, current_label=None):
    if not current_ax:
        current_ax=plt.gca()
        
    if not current_label:
        current_label="missing label"
        
    current_ax.plot(x, y, label=current_label)
    plt.sca(current_ax)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(6, 8))

#normal plot into panel 1
x1 = np.arange(6)
y1 = np.random.randint(1, 10, len(x1))
draw_the_line(x1, y1, ax1, "data1")

#normal plot into panel 2
x2 = np.arange(5)
y2 = np.random.randint(10, 20, len(x2))
draw_the_line(x2, y2, ax2, "data2")

#plot into panel 1 with missing label
x3 = np.arange(4)
y3 = np.random.randint(20, 30, len(x3))
draw_the_line(x3, y3, ax1)

#plot into the last panel used
x4 = np.arange(3)
y4 = np.random.randint(30, 40, len(x4))
draw_the_line(x4, y4, current_label="data4")

ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]